# What exactly is groupID for AWS::ec2::SecurityGroupIngress?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

I have a neptune cluster I'm defining a security group for

```
PrivateSecurityGroup:
  Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
  Properties:
    GroupName: private-${self:service}
    GroupDescription: 'Security group for private subnet access to ${self:service} stack'
    VpcId: ${self:custom.dmzVpc.id}

PrivateSecurityGroupIngress:
  Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
  Properties:
    IpProtocol: tcp
    FromPort: 8182
    ToPort: 8182
    GroupId:
      Fn::GetAtt: [PrivateSecurityGroup, GroupId]
    SourceSecurityGroupId:
      Fn::GetAtt: [PrivateSecurityGroup, GroupId]
```

What is GroupId?  If I don't add it I get an error `Exactly one of GroupName and GroupId must be specified`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-ingress.html

The descriptions for GroupId and SourceSecurityGroupId are pretty similar, I couldn't find any better documentation explaining the differences

Answer (score 1):

I think I get it

GroupID is the SecurityGroup that the rule is associated to

SourceSecurityGroupID is ID of a security group other AWS instances are associated with that can access this group.

So actually I would want 2 separate groups, and my lambdas would be associated with PrivateSecurityGroup, and they would get access to my Neptune cluster which has NeptuneSecurityGroup

```
PrivateSecurityGroup:
  Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
  Properties:
    GroupName: private-${self:service}
    GroupDescription: 'Security group for private subnet access to ${self:service} stack'
    VpcId: ${self:custom.dmzVpc.id}

NeptuneSecurityGroup:
  Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
  Properties:
    VpcId: ${cf:${self:custom.dmzVpc.serviceName}.DmzVpcId}
    GroupDescription: Allows access to Neptune
    SecurityGroupIngress:
      - SourceSecurityGroupId:
          Ref: PrivateSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: 8182
      ToPort: 8182
```

Comment: Yes, the SourceXYZ properties relate to the source of the network traffic that will be allowed through the Security Group whose ID is GroupID (or whose name is GroupName).